# Graphics tablet won't affect mouse cursor location, Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: graphics-tablet

Programs will still interact with the tablet but my cursor wont move. This causes problems that I don't know how to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it took me a while to find the rather simple solution.

Switch back from wayland to xorg by logout, change the setting, log back in.
Here is a more detailed explanation:
https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/